# How can I add custom text to the bars in echarts and modify the color of the hovering ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, echarts

I am new using this library, and basically I would like to change the texts that are shown in the tooltip and in the label of the bars. I would also like to know how to modify the color of the bars to my liking.
To try to change the text, I am putting an array of test texts so that when I do a hovering on the bar, the text corresponds to the position of the data.

```
var data = [[0,0,5],[0,1,1],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0],[0,6,0],[0,7,0],[0,8,0],[0,9,0],[0,10,0],[0,11,2],[0,12,4],[0,13,1],[0,14,1],[0,15,3],[0,16,4],[0,17,6],[0,18,4],[0,19,4],[0,20,3],[0,21,3],[0,22,2],[0,23,5],[1,0,7],[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,4,0],[1,5,0],[1,6,0],[1,7,0],[1,8,0],[1,9,0],[1,10,5],[1,11,2],[1,12,2],[1,13,6],[1,14,9],[1,15,11],[1,16,6],[1,17,7],[1,18,8],[1,19,12],[1,20,5],[1,21,5],[1,22,7],[1,23,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,0],[2,7,0],[2,8,0],[2,9,0],[2,10,3],[2,11,2],[2,12,1],[2,13,9],[2,14,8],[2,15,10],[2,16,6],[2,17,5],[2,18,5],[2,19,5],[2,20,7],[2,21,4],[2,22,2],[2,23,4],[3,0,7],[3,1,3],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[3,4,0],[3,5,0],[3,6,0],[3,7,0],[3,8,1],[3,9,0],[3,10,5],[3,11,4],[3,12,7],[3,13,14],[3,14,13],[3,15,12],[3,16,9],[3,17,5],[3,18,5],[3,19,10],[3,20,6],[3,21,4],[3,22,4],[3,23,1],[4,0,1],[4,1,3],[4,2,0],[4,3,0],[4,4,0],[4,5,1],[4,6,0],[4,7,0],[4,8,0],[4,9,2],[4,10,4],[4,11,4],[4,12,2],[4,13,4],[4,14,4],[4,15,14],[4,16,12],[4,17,1],[4,18,8],[4,19,5],[4,20,3],[4,21,7],[4,22,3],[4,23,0],[5,0,2],[5,1,1],[5,2,0],[5,3,3],[5,4,0],[5,5,0],[5,6,0],[5,7,0],[5,8,2],[5,9,0],[5,10,4],[5,11,1],[5,12,5],[5,13,10],[5,14,5],[5,15,7],[5,16,11],[5,17,6],[5,18,0],[5,19,5],[5,20,3],[5,21,4],[5,22,2],[5,23,0],[6,0,1],[6,1,0],[6,2,0],[6,3,0],[6,4,0],[6,5,0],[6,6,0],[6,7,0],[6,8,0],[6,9,0],[6,10,1],[6,11,0],[6,12,2],[6,13,1],[6,14,3],[6,15,4],[6,16,0],[6,17,0],[6,18,0],[6,19,0],[6,20,1],[6,21,2],[6,22,2],[6,23,6]];

for(var i in data){
    text_toltip.push("my text"+i);
}
```

this is my code:

```
var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var hours = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
                '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
                '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
                '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
var days = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
                'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'];

var text_toltip=[];

var data = [[0,0,5],[0,1,1],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0],[0,6,0],[0,7,0],[0,8,0],[0,9,0],[0,10,0],[0,11,2],[0,12,4],[0,13,1],[0,14,1],[0,15,3],[0,16,4],[0,17,6],[0,18,4],[0,19,4],[0,20,3],[0,21,3],[0,22,2],[0,23,5],[1,0,7],[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,4,0],[1,5,0],[1,6,0],[1,7,0],[1,8,0],[1,9,0],[1,10,5],[1,11,2],[1,12,2],[1,13,6],[1,14,9],[1,15,11],[1,16,6],[1,17,7],[1,18,8],[1,19,12],[1,20,5],[1,21,5],[1,22,7],[1,23,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,0],[2,7,0],[2,8,0],[2,9,0],[2,10,3],[2,11,2],[2,12,1],[2,13,9],[2,14,8],[2,15,10],[2,16,6],[2,17,5],[2,18,5],[2,19,5],[2,20,7],[2,21,4],[2,22,2],[2,23,4],[3,0,7],[3,1,3],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[3,4,0],[3,5,0],[3,6,0],[3,7,0],[3,8,1],[3,9,0],[3,10,5],[3,11,4],[3,12,7],[3,13,14],[3,14,13],[3,15,12],[3,16,9],[3,17,5],[3,18,5],[3,19,10],[3,20,6],[3,21,4],[3,22,4],[3,23,1],[4,0,1],[4,1,3],[4,2,0],[4,3,0],[4,4,0],[4,5,1],[4,6,0],[4,7,0],[4,8,0],[4,9,2],[4,10,4],[4,11,4],[4,12,2],[4,13,4],[4,14,4],[4,15,14],[4,16,12],[4,17,1],[4,18,8],[4,19,5],[4,20,3],[4,21,7],[4,22,3],[4,23,0],[5,0,2],[5,1,1],[5,2,0],[5,3,3],[5,4,0],[5,5,0],[5,6,0],[5,7,0],[5,8,2],[5,9,0],[5,10,4],[5,11,1],[5,12,5],[5,13,10],[5,14,5],[5,15,7],[5,16,11],[5,17,6],[5,18,0],[5,19,5],[5,20,3],[5,21,4],[5,22,2],[5,23,0],[6,0,1],[6,1,0],[6,2,0],[6,3,0],[6,4,0],[6,5,0],[6,6,0],[6,7,0],[6,8,0],[6,9,0],[6,10,1],[6,11,0],[6,12,2],[6,13,1],[6,14,3],[6,15,4],[6,16,0],[6,17,0],[6,18,0],[6,19,0],[6,20,1],[6,21,2],[6,22,2],[6,23,6]];

for(var i in data){
    text_toltip.push("my text"+i);
}
chart.setOption({
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    tooltip: {},
    visualMap: {
      max: 20,
      color: ['#d94e5d','#eac736','#50a3ba']
    },
    xAxis3D: {
      type: 'category',
      data: hours
    },
    yAxis3D: {
      type: 'category',
      data: days
    },
    zAxis3D: {
      type: 'value',
      min: 1
    },
    grid3D: {
      boxWidth: 200,
      boxDepth: 80,
      environment: 'none',
      viewControl: {
      // projection: 'orthographic'
    },
    light: {
      main: {
        shadow: true
      },
      ambient: {
        intensity: 0
      },
      ambientCubemap: {
        texture: 'asset/pisa.hdr',
        diffuseIntensity: 1
      }
  }
},
series: [{
  type: 'bar3D',
  data: data.map(function (item) {
    return {
      value: [item[1], item[0], item[2]],
      label: {
        show: item[2] != 0
      }
    }
  }),
  shading: 'lambert',
    label: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    },
    emphasis: {
      label: {
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 20,
          color: '#900'
        }
      },
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#900'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

how can I do it?

https://plnkr.co/edit/LZnJdUDRQHdCRKnldWCL?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if I understand your questions correctly:

- to change visualMap.color property which specifies colors used for gradient

e.g.

```
visualMap: {
  max: 20,
  color: ['#00ff00','#0000ff'] // start and end colors for gradient 
},
```

- You can add `name` property to each of your axises

e.g.

```
   yAxis3D: {
    type: 'category',
    data: days,
    name: 'days'
   },
```

- to change text of your tooltips you add tooltip with formatter

e.g.

```
 tooltip: {                
    formatter: 'my custom text and {a}, {b}, {c}, {d} and {e}'
 },
```

alternatively formatter can be provided as a [callback](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter):

```
 tooltip: {
    formatter: function(params, ticket, callback) {
      return  "my text, value: " + params.value;
    }
 }
```

Using callback you can get detailed text from the server.

I also forked your plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/fpyhLHUZ2VAPdeQWnw4E?p=preview

UPDATE: https://plnkr.co/edit/JJMoWpZVhfyQOjdTYDvB?p=preview - this version uses your array of tooltips

Basically what you need in your case is `params.dataIndex` property:

```
tooltip: {
 formatter: function(params) { 
   return " " + params.value + ", " + text_toltip[params.dataIndex];  
 } 
},
```

Comment: thanks man! you are the best.. I have a question, how can add a custom text dynamic en the tooltip. for example:                          value: [item[0], item[1], item[2], 'custom text']

Comment: I am trying to add a text in the tooltip that can be obtained dynamically. I put it as the fourth element in this array, but this damages the color of the bars.

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116605/modify-the-heigth-of-the-bars-series-in-echarts