# modify the heigth of the bars series in echarts

Tags: echarts

I currently have a map loaded, and I have some bars on the map. I would like to include my variable `text_toltip[i]` in the tooltip so that the coordinates and text of the variable `text_toltip[i]` are displayed in each bar. how can I do it? I'm new in this library.

I know that there is an attribute called minHeight, which allows to establish a minimum height for the bars, but I would like to establish a maximum predetermined size for the bars and so the other sizes and colors of the bars are calculated. how can I do it?

```
  series: [{
      type: 'bar3D',
      coordinateSystem: 'geo3D',
      barSize:0.05,
      minHeight:0.05,
      data: data.map(function (item) {
      return {
          value: [item[0], item[1], item[2]],
          label: {
              show: false
          }
      }
      }),
      shading: 'lambert'
  }]
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Tdwwk8yKCi0fiY7I3AqK?p=preview

Thank you.

Comment: really cool chart, but i can't find how to control height properly. try to normalize value (3rd number) , e.g. find max and do `item[2] * 10/max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question,I read the Echarts's documentation and found a property belonging to "geo3D called "boxHeight" ,which can play the same role as you say "maxheight".I've tested it,no problem.
[boxHeight](http://echarts.baidu.com/option-gl.html#geo3D.boxHeight)